# ColdFusion how to get a message from cfcatch

Tags: coldfusion, try-catch, cfml

I'm doing a cffile upload, and want to trap any errors in the MIME type.  I wrote this code:

```
 <form 
 enctype= "multipart/form-data" 
 method = "post" 
 name   = "templupload"  
 action = "frag2.cfm">

<cftry>
   <cffile action = "upload"
    destination   = "#session.exploc#"
    fileField     = "form.theupload"
    mode          = '666'
    accept        = 'html'
    strict        = 'true'
    result        = 'ss'
    nameConflict  = "Overwrite">

    <!--- bad mime type files --->
    <cfcatch type = 'any'>   
       <cfif FindNoCase("The MIME type or the Extension of the uploaded file", cfcatch.message)>
       <cfoutput>
          <script>
             document.getElementById('tmpl').innerHTML = "error";
          </script>
       </cfoutput>   
       </cfif>
    </cfcatch>

 <cfthrow type="any" message="got an error" />         
</cftry>
```

When I try to upload a wrong MIME type, it does not load, which is good. The form is submitting which is not good but I'll deal with that later.  My problem now is I have been unable to get a message about the error to show up anywhere.  I have tried the following:

```
<cfcatch.message = 'error'; 
<script>alert('error');</script>
<script> document.getElementById('tmpl').innerHTML = "error";</script>
   <!--- this 2nd script does not work regardless of whether the tmpl
         id is on the original page or the target page --->  
<cfoutput> error </cfoutput>
<p> error </p>
<cfthrow type = 'any' message = 'error' />
<cfdump var = "#catch#"  or var = '#catch.message#"
```

I have tried all these inside and outside of the cfcatch tag, but always within the cftry tag. All of these approaches were in the research I did, but none of them are working for me.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
 <cftry>

 <cfcatch>
      <cfset request.error = cfcatch.message>
 <cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

Then much much later

```
<cfif request.keyExists('error')>
    <cfoutput>#request.error#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: But now it is also not accepting a .html file.  That file was created by saving a Libre Office file in html mode.  It is opening perfectly in the browser.   Under properties it is showing as text/html, which is exactly what the upload is asking for.  Any thoughts?

Comment: In `cffile`, the `accept` attribute should be a comma-delimited list of mime-types. Instead of `accept = "html"`, try `accept = "text/html"`.

Comment: +1 for using `keyExists()` instead of the legacy `structKeyExists()`.  Coming here to stack overflow helps give me a constant reminder to use modern techniques and breaking old coding habits. :)

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno -- yessss -- that worked.  Do you think  I should also include text/htm?

Comment: @user12031119 -- How nice of you to give me a +1 for using keyExists(), but it is James Mohler who suggested that.  Regretfully I am not good enough at this yet to have any old bad habits.  On the bright side, I have plenty of not-so-old bad code created before I learned more.

Comment: It is so nice to come here to Stack Overflow and find solutions.  I do try to research things before asking, but often I cannot find answers.

Comment: @BettyMock `text/html` is all you'll need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types